# OpenAI use case —> data insights, storytelling

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

My use case: draw insights, data storytelling from tabular data (rows / columns - e-commerce store purchase time series)

Is ChatGPT good for that purpose?
(My data is not textual, it’s user behaviorial data ( flow on the e-commerce store!)

For validation, I currently copy/paste raw data table into ChatGPT window —> give my prompt —> and it outputs the insights. This is working great. esp for data storytelling.

Now I want to scale and build an app using OpenAI API.  But I’ll soon run out of max_token limit per prompt when feeding data at scale (last 3 years data time series data for ex.)

What architecture can help me solve this challenge ?

Any idea, lead will be highly appreciable.